# Modal/Popup Changing Start Position if Scrolling Prior to Click

Tags: javascript, scroll, popup, position

Good morning everyone. I have a novice JS question that I need help clearing up. First off I am an extreme beginner and self taught so forgive any ignorance.

I am building a new website for a business and one of the pages has a grid of products for customers. Each product has a button which creates a modal to give more information about the product. I am using a JS I found online to have DIFFERENT Modals inside some of these other modals. If you click the modal in question (star fish or sea horse) after scrolling the page first, the modals appear further down and cut off by the screen.

example: https://my.duda.co/preview/27d7a4cc?device=desktop&pageId=30782523

I know the author of the JS included a var to reposition the modal if the user had scrolled but it is not working in my favor or there is something more I need to do and don't have the knowledge for it.

I also know the code is sloppy and probably redundant in some places, I am not an expert. My JSFiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/shnt7vwu](https://jsfiddle.net/TheTaxButler/shnt7vwu/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=shnt7vwu)

```
<script>
var $html = $(document.documentElement);
var $modal = $('.modal-container');
function showModal() {
$html.css('overflow', 'hidden');
$modal.show().css('overflow', 'auto');
}
function hideModal() {
$html.css('overflow', 'visible');
$modal.show().css('overflow','visible')
}
$('.modal-btn').on('click', showModal);
$('.modal-close').on('click', hideModal);
</script>
<script>
var scrollTop = '';
var newHeight = '100';
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
scrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
newHeight = scrollTop + 100;
});
$('.popup-trigger').click(function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
if(jQuery(window).width() < 767) {
$(this).after( $(this).nextAll('.popup:first') );
$(this).nextAll('.popup:first').show().addClass
('popup-mobile').css('top', 0);
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $(this).nextAll('.popup:first').offset().top
}, 500);
} else {
$('.popup').hide();
$(this).nextAll('.popup:first').removeClass('popup-mobile').css
('top', newHeight).toggle();
};
});
$('html').click(function() {
$('.popup').hide();
});
$('.popup-btn-close').click(function(e){
$(this).parent().hide();
});
$('.popup').click(function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
```

Comment: When posting code here, please follow this article, it will help you get better feedback.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I went ahead and reworked the post with a link for external viewing on JS to make things easier. I also only included the JS since this is the issue that is causing the repositioning of the modals.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your whole 'div body grid' stuff inside a div with `overflow-y` enabled, then have your modals with `vh:100` hidden outside

Just disable all the modals, div property until the correct user action is taken.

This way you can avoid calculations which may break between platforms and in edge cases.

Comment: I'm sure it's not the ideal answer, but I hope it's better than nothing.